# Python socket server and client, keeps losing connection

Tags: python, sockets, serial-port, arduino, pyserial

I am expanding on a GUI program for a remotely controlled robot. The idea is to program a simple GUI client in Python that connects to a remote server, also written in Python.  The client would send simple messages to the server, the server would receive the message, and then transmit it via serial to an [Arduino Mega](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega) that is connected via USB.

I have gotten the code to work, kind of.

Right now, I can connect one time from my client Python GUI, send one message, then it loses connection.  Then I must halt the server, restart it, and then send another single message.

What is happening here?

Here is the server script, adopted from another source.

```
import serial
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('', 9000))
sock.listen(1)
print "Listening on TCP 9000"
motor = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1)
print "Connected to Arduino Mega at: /dev/ttyUSB0"
while(1):
    print "Waiting For Connection..."
    connection, addr = sock.accept()
    connection.setblocking(0)
    print "Connected by", addr[0]
    while(1):
        try:
            sockdata = connection.recv(1)
            break
        except:
            pass
    if sockdata == 'X':
        print "Exiting"
        break
    if sockdata == '0':
        print "Stopping"
        motor.write(sockdata)
    if sockdata == '1':
        print "Forward"
        motor.write(sockdata)
    if sockdata == '2':
        print "Left"
        motor.write(sockdata)
    if sockdata == '3':
        print "Right"
        motor.write(sockdata)
    if sockdata == '4':
        motor.write(sockdata)
        print "Backwards"
    else:
        pass
```

And here is my client code, minus the resource file of course.

```
from socket import *
from PythonCard import model
HOST = ''
PORT = 9000
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)

Client = socket (AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
Client.connect((ADDR))

class MainWindow(model.Background):
    def on_FwdBtn_mouseClick(self, event):
        Client.send('1')
    def on_LftBtn_mouseClick(self, event):
        Client.send('2')
    def on_RitBtn_mouseClick(self, event):
        Client.send('3')
    def on_RevBtn_mouseClick(self, event):
        Client.send('4')
    def on_StpBtn_mouseClick(self, event):
        Client.send('0')
    def on_GetPing_mouseClick(self, event):
        Client.send('~')


app = model.Application(MainWindow)
app.MainLoop()
```

*EDIT*

After looking into the below fixes or at least some of them, here is my code for the server now, the client remains the same.

```
import serial
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('', 9001))
sock.listen(1)
print "Listening on TCP 9001"
motor = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1)
print "Connected to Motor Controller: /dev/ttyUSB0"
print "Waiting For Connection..."
connection, addr = sock.accept()
connection.setblocking(0)
while(1):

    print "Connected by", addr[0]
    while(1):
        try:
            sockdata = connection.recv(1024)
            break
        except:
            pass
    if sockdata == 'X':
        print "Exiting"
        break
    if sockdata == '0':
        print "Stopping"
        motor.write(sockdata)
    if sockdata == '1':
        print "Forward"
        motor.write(sockdata)
    if sockdata == '2':
        print "Left"
        motor.write(sockdata)
    if sockdata == '3':
        print "Right"
        motor.write(sockdata)
    if sockdata == '4':
        motor.write(sockdata)
        print "Backwards"
    else:
        pass
```

This works a little better, but still not right I don't think. When I run this I get the server running, and after starting my GUI, I can watch my terminal window on the server and will get the actual commands as they come through

> "Connected from 127.0.0.1" "Forward" 
>   "Connected from 127.0.0.1"  "left" 
>   "Connected from 127.0.0.1"  "right" 
>   "Connected from 127.0.0.1"

It looks as though each time I send a command I get reconnected.  I want to maintain a connection once I start my GUI, not disconnect and reconnect each time I send a command. 
Sorry if I sound kind of stupid in this, but I just started with Python about three weeks ago.

Comment: Avoid bare excepts, they can hide all kinds of errors. Also, use "elif" where the sequence of ifs are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `accept()` inside the loop, which will block for another connection. The original connection will be dereferenced and automatically closed when/if another connection comes in. Normally, you spawn an independent handler (fork, thread, or add to async event handler) to handle new connections that does the work.